# GWT displaying many menuItems

Tags: gwt, menuitem, menubar

I'm having a MenuBar with n MenuItems. So if n is an high number I have many MenuItems. So I'm searching for an way to display them under my conditions.
for example: n= 8
*After n=5 the List splits in to blocks:

```
 |------------| |------------|
 |n=0         | |n=6         |
 |n=1         | |n=7         |
 |n=2         | |n=8         |
 |n=3         | |------------|
 |n=4         |
 |n=5         |
 |------------|
```

and not

```
 |------------| 
 |n=0         | 
 |n=1         |
 |n=2         | 
 |n=3         | 
 |n=4         |
 |n=5         |
 |n=6         |
 |n=7         |
 |n=8         |
 |------------|
```

Because its destroying the page layout. Hopefully my kinda strange explanation can show u my problem. thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I have not seen such behavior implemented in a menu!!!
2. The scroll on the menu is also a bit weird and will look something like this.

If you wish to add scroll to menu then the style to edit would be as below :

```
.gwt-MenuBarPopup {
    overflow-y: scroll !important;
    height: 70px !important;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As you can decide only once weather the `menu bar` style `vertical or horizontal`. I.e at the time of initialization of [MenuBar(boolean vertical)](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/MenuBar.html#MenuBar%28boolean%29).

So in the middle of population you can't change it.

If you think the `menuitems list` is very large you can simple apply `scroll` inside the `menu` by applying styles like below

```
.gwt-MenuBar-vertical {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
    height: 70px;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```